# Materialize chips initialization

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, materialize

I would like to add dynamically some materialize chips.

```
 $('.chips-initial').material_chip({
                        data: [{
                                tag: 'Apple'
                            }, {
                                tag: 'Microsoft'
                            }, {
                                tag: 'Google'
                            }]
                    });
```

Like above but the values I want to give are dynamic.
How can I create an data object like above to pass it as parameter?
Thank you in advance

Comment: I would suspect that you could create your own array of objects and pass that variable array instead of hard coding it.

Answer (score 4):

Basically what happens here is when the page loads it populates the text string values found in metaTags that were inserted into a hidden field from the database. The for loop iterates into the necessary chips-initial.

```
 var tagsMeta = [];
    //alert(tagsMeta);
    var tagsString = document.getElementById('metaTags').value;
    //alert(tagsString);
    var tagsArray = tagsString.split(',');
    for(i=0; i < tagsArray.length; i++) {
      tagsMeta.push({tag: tagsArray[i]});
    }

    $('.chips-initial').material_chip({
        data: tagsMeta
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

As I commented, you could create your own array of values and pass that to `data`. This might look like:

```
var myData = [
  {
    tag: 'iPhone'
  }, {
    tag: 'Windows Phone'
  }, {
    tag: 'Android Phone'
  }
];

$('.chips-initial').material_chip({
  data: myData
});
```

Wokring Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/en6r0ucb/

Answer (score 0):

I found solution

```
                    var authData = [];
                    var tag = {};
                    tag["tag"] = yourString;
                    authData.push(tag);
                    $('.chips-initial').material_chip({
                        data: authData
                    });
```